# array.push(item) in async/await promise return no object

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I want to push all volume to "klht" array but its not work, "klht" return no object. "dataViewerFirst" is response from server, console.log('vol '+volume) had value. But console.log('v '+klht) return no object
Please help me solve the code if you can. That is my gratitude to you. Thank in advanced.

```
var klht = [];
dataViewerFirst.forEach(obj => {
    var externalId = obj.externalId;
    var _projectName = obj.projectName;
    var status = obj.status;
    if(externalId !== null && externalId !== undefined && _projectName === projectName && status === 1){
        
        viewer.model.getExternalIdMapping(data => first(data));
        async function first(data){
            dbId = data[externalId];
            await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                viewer.getProperties(dbId, function(e){
                    var propertiesObj = e.properties;
                    propertiesObj.forEach(myF);
                    function myF(obj){
                        if(obj.displayName === "Volume"){
                            var volume = obj.displayValue;
                            klht.push(volume);
                            console.log('vol '+volume);
                        }
                    }
                    return resolve();
                });
                
            })
            //return resolve();
        }
    }
})
console.log('v '+klht);
```

Comment: Convert all callback functions (getExternalIdMapping, getProperties) to Promise functions. User for-loop instead of forEach

Comment: Thank for your comment. But I'm new  in javascript, please write code because i can't write correct. Thank in advanced

Comment: what does `viewer.model.getExternalIdMapping` do? It's not related to the rest of your code, i.e. its return value does not depend on `obj`. So why is it called for every `obj`?

Comment: Do you need something like this - https://codesandbox.io/s/code-snippets-w82ue?file=/src/index.js:300-578?